# Ubuntu can't mount swap from RAID1

Tags: raid, boot, swap, fstab

I have just built a new server to host a minecraft server. I have two hdds that are in hardware raid 1, and I have installed Ubuntu Server 11.04 on those disks. My problem is that anytime I reboot I get this error message

```
The disk drive for /dev/mapper/nvidia_dhecicai5 is not ready yet or not present
Continue to wait; or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

This is my */etc/fstab*

```
proc                             /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid    0       0
/dev/mapper/nvidia_dhecicai1     /               ext4    errors=remount-ro      0       1
/dev/mapper/nvidia_dhecicai5    none            swap    sw                     0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1           none            swap    sw                     0       0
ramdisk                          /mnt/ramdisk    tmpfs   mode=1777,size=2g      0       0
```

If comment out the first swap line i get the same error message with cryptswap1, and if I comment out both the system boots fine. I have 8g of ram in the system, so it should work fine without swap, but it's kind of an ugly solution. I probably could get rid of the cryptswap1 swap by reinstalling without encrypted home folders, but I'm pretty sure it's the same problem.

This is my output from *blkid*

```
  /dev/sda: TYPE="nvidia_raid_member"
  /dev/sdb: TYPE="nvidia_raid_member"
  /dev/mapper/nvidia_dhecicai1: UUID="28a0d47a-8a42-4a7d-83f4-09d89b206901" TYPE="ext4"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need **lvm** and **dmraid** in your initrd. Obviously you are using an nvidia "RAID" controller chip (is this a server?). This chip needs software in the OS that supports this raid - only then the raid is available in the OS. (as opposed to "real" raid controllers that present the raid as disk to the OS).

Comment: I'm using the raid controller on the Asus M4N68T. The system is supposed to function as a dedicated minecraft server. Is this something that I can fix (more or less easily) without reinstalling, or should I do a new install. And if I do a new install, what should I do differently? I partitioned the whole raid1 without LVM.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall anything. You just need to add an additional kernel-module to your initrd. Can you post your output of `sudo lsmod`?